# How to integrate IronPython to run a embedded Python Script

Tags: python, c#, ironpython

I have 2 Python Scripts embedded into my C# Application. Essentially; 1 python script is a Decode Script and the other Script is to Encode. The idea that I have is; how can I execute these python scripts using IronPython against a selected file to decode or encode the selected file? This is my current code as of now:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;
using System.Net;

namespace NGH_WC_Data_Extractor_V1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("Decode");
            listBox1.Items.Add("Encode");

        }

        public static int DownloadFile(String remoteFilename,
                                       String localFilename)
        {
            // Function will return the number of bytes processed
            // to the caller. Initialize to 0 here.
            int bytesProcessed = 0;

            // Assign values to these objects here so that they can
            // be referenced in the finally block
            Stream remoteStream = null;
            Stream localStream = null;
            WebResponse response = null;

            // Use a try/catch/finally block as both the WebRequest and Stream
            // classes throw exceptions upon error
            try
            {
                // Create a request for the specified remote file name
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(remoteFilename);
                if (request != null)
                {
                    // Send the request to the server and retrieve the
                    // WebResponse object 
                    response = request.GetResponse();
                    if (response != null)
                    {
                        // Once the WebResponse object has been retrieved,
                        // get the stream object associated with the response's data
                        remoteStream = response.GetResponseStream();

                        // Create the local file
                        localStream = File.Create(localFilename);

                        // Allocate a 1k buffer
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[12582912];
                        int bytesRead;

                        // Simple do/while loop to read from stream until
                        // no bytes are returned
                        do
                        {
                            // Read data (up to 1k) from the stream
                            bytesRead = remoteStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                            // Write the data to the local file
                            localStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                            // Increment total bytes processed
                            bytesProcessed += bytesRead;
                        } while (bytesRead > 0);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Close the response and streams objects here 
                // to make sure they're closed even if an exception
                // is thrown at some point
                if (response != null) response.Close();
                if (remoteStream != null) remoteStream.Close();
                if (localStream != null) localStream.Close();
            }

            // Return total bytes processed to caller.
            return bytesProcessed;
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string download = textBox1.Text;
            string name = textBox4.Text;

            int read = DownloadFile(download, name + ".data");
            Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes written", read);
            label6.Visible = true;
        }
        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button4_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label9.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + " Selected";
            SELECTPYTHONSCRIPT();
        }

        private void SELECTPYTHONSCRIPT()
        {
            if (label9.Text == "Encode Selected")
            {
                label10.Text = "Encoding Script Enabled...";
            }
            if (label9.Text == "Decode Selected")
            {
                label10.Text = "Decoding Script Enabled...";

            }
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            textBox5.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I just do not know where to look since the resources to call IronPython on a script that is embedded is limited and I just need help getting pointed in the right direction.

Comment: This may help: https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython3/tree/master/Src/IronPythonCompiler as you can see, you can install the compiler and invoke it in various ways including by referencing the assembly. Your security should be highly rigorous. If anyone can tamper with the server that provides the script, you will be completely vulnerable